# Is there a java equivalent of python's dict.items()/dict.values()/dict.keys()?

Tags: java, python, dictionary, hashmap

I am currently learning Java, having had experience in Python already. I understand that the closest thing to Python dictionaries in Java is `HashMap` and I am curious if there is a `HashMap` equivalent for Python's dict.items()/dict.values()/dict.keys() - I understand `HashMap` has a `get()` method but I want to retrieve values without knowing the keys of the `Map`.

If there is no equivalent, how do you recommend I get around this problem? Do not use `HashMap` at all or?

Comment: The `Map` available methods are described on [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) java doc page

Comment: What does "retrieve items without knowing the keys" mean?  You can get all the values as a collection.  Is that what you want?

Comment: The current behavior of those Python methods was actually [*based on*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/) the corresponding Java methods.

Comment: Please read [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) first, then ask here whenever you find a problem you cannot solve.

Answer (score 7):

`Map.entrySet()`, `Map.values()`, `Map.keySet()`. Take a look at [`Map` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) which lists all the methods in `Map` interface and what is their role.